# threejs multiple scenes with dedicated cameras

Tags: three.js

I want to use a single canvas for several totally different scenes for a website. The most clean solution I found is to make custom scene classes in which I'd add a camera, and I'd render the corresponding scene using a public property "camera" of my custom scene. Basic implementation looks like this :

CustomScene1.js

```js
//... imports

export class CustomScene1 extends THREE.Scene {
     constructor() {
        super();
        this.camera = new THREE.PerspectiveCamera(25,window.screenWidth / window.screenHeight,0.1,1000);
        // instantiate 3D objects...
        this.add(meshes);
      }
      //Do the scene stuff...
}
```

Main.js

```js
import { CustomScene1 } from '../CustomScene1';
import { CustomScene2 } from '../CustomScene2';

cScene1 = new CustomScene1();
cScene2 = new CustomScene2();
showScene1 = true;
camera = new THREE.PerspectiveCamera(25,window.screenWidth / window.screenHeight,0.1,1000);
//
const animate = () => {
     requestAnimationFrame(animate);
     if(showScene1) {
          renderer.render(cScene1, cScene1.camera); // NOT OK
          renderer.render(cScene1, camera); // OK
      } else {
          renderer.render(cScene2, cScene2.camera);
     }
}
```

To embedding the camera inside the scene feels much more cleaner as the cameras have specific behaviours I don't want to mix.

PROBLEM : My problem is that if in the render() call I use the camera contained in the customScene nothing shows, but if I create a camera in the Main and use it then it works...

Any idea why ? Or shoud I should another structure ?

Thx a lot for your help

Answer (score 0):

im not sure but try clear() before rendering

and you can try to call you class to render "renderer"

```
  renderer.clear()
  renderer.render(this.scene, this.camera); // not in your case
  renderer.autoClear = false
  CustomScene1.render( this.renderer )
  renderer.autoClear = true
```

check ViewHelper example to construct your custom class scene

hope it helps you

Comment: Thanks for your help. calling `.clear()` does not work. My main problem is that it seems not to be able to access the camera property inside my custom scene.
`CustomScene1.render(this.renderer)` throws an error